# Do not run @After("@tag") hook if assertion fails

Tags: java, cucumber, testng, bdd

I have the below scenario in java bdd:

- A tag that will create some data: `@Before` which will create some data before running the test steps
- Test case with steps: `Scenario` having tag @DeleteData
- After tag which will delete data `@After("@DeleteData)`

**Actual: ** `@After("DeleteData)` runs even if my `Then` assertion fails

**Expected: ** Do not run `@After("@DeleteData)` method should delete the data in order to investigate

Any help to achieve this?

```
@DeleteData
Scenario: 
  Given User is at FB login page
  When User logs in
  Then Success message is displayed: Logged in successfully
```

```
Hooks.java 

@Before("DeleteData)
public void before() {
 // Create some data
}

@After("DeleteData)
public void after() {
 // delete data
}
```

```
StepFile.java

Given("^User is at FB login page$", () -> {
 // Login logic
});

When("^User logs in$", () -> {
 // Login logic
});

The("^Success message is displayed: (.*)$", (String msg) -> {
 assertThat(msg).isEqualTo("Logged in successfully");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cucumber can inject `Scenario` object into your hook method. So you can just do something like this:

```java
@After
public void doAfter(Scenario scenario){
    if(scenario.getStatus() == Status.PASSED){
        // Do whatever you should
    }
}
```

So the code inside would not execute if your scenario has completed with any different status.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution. For now, this will work for me but in case if you find something else please add it here as in my case my `@After("@tags")` will grow a lot with different different tags and I don't want to add if condition for all of them

Answer (score 0):

It's expected that the `After` code always run. It should be able to run no matter which steps ran or failed.

To do that, you mighr want to set a flag like `hasSucceeded` (class variable) in the appropriate step and read it from the the `After` code.